# Linq - where clause on child object

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following classes:

```
public class Nation
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; private set; }
}

public class City
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Assume `Nation` is the aggregate root and so I only have a `NationRepository` and not a `CityRepository` (thus `Nation` is the starting point for Linq queries). To clarify, my starting point would be an `IQueryable<Nation>` object.

How would I write a query which returns a collection of `City` objects according to the following logic:

Select all `City` instances whose `Name` begins with 'M' whose parent `Nation`'s name is 'UK'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would do the following:

```
var results = NationRepository.Where(n => n.Name == "UK")
                              .SelectMany(n => n.Cities)
                              .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("M"));
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
from n in Nation
where n.Name == "UK"
from c in n.Cities
where c.Name.StartsWith("M")
select c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = nations.Where(n => n.Name == "UK")
                    .SelectMany(n => n.Cities)
                    .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("M"));
```

EDIT: Since @Justin Niessner beat me... maybe nest the second where clause

```
var result = nations.Where(n => n.Name == "UK")
                    .SelectMany(n => n.Cities.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("M"));
```